# Why foreach causes an error when using it with itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, foreach

Partial code is:

```
private void ListFieldNames()
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"c:\Temp\PDF\fw4.pdf";

            // title the form
            this.Text += " - " + pdfTemplate;

            // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

            // create and populate a string builder with each of the 
            // field names available in the subject PDF
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
                sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            // Write the string builder's content to the form's textbox
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        }
```

I am getting the following error:

`Error  1   Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item>' to 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'   c:\Users\usrs\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\PDFTest SLN\PDFTest\Form1.cs    50  13  PDFTest`

I am using VS 2012.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Rather than `DictionaryEntry de` why don't you put `KeyValuePair<string,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item> de` Seems there's no implicit conversion. Or I guess you could just use `var` for readability and let the compiler figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says: because `Fields` is a collection of `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item>` not `DictionaryEntry`.

You should use explicitly `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,iTextSharp.text.pdf.AcroFields.Item>` type or use `var` keyword and let the compiler determine the type.

I suggest following code:

```
foreach (var de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
{
    sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```